# Optional of what is equivalent to Optional.empty()? Or, a better way to write this

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I found myself writing this:

```
Optional<String> s = fooMaybe.map(Foo::getName).orElse(Optional.empty());
```

Of course, for the return types to match the compilable way is:

```
Optional<String> s = fooMaybe.map(foo -> Optional.of(foo.getName)).orElse(Optional.empty());
```

But is there not a more succinct way? *e.g.* Does `Optional.of(null)` return `Optional.empty()`?

```
Optional<String> s = Optional.of(fooMaybe.map(Foo::getName).orElse(null));
```

Comment: Pretty sure there's something painfully obvious I'm missing :-)

Comment: `fooMaybe.map(Foo::getName)SEMICOLON`?

Comment: @Michael - Yup... thanks. (Had just figured it out myself too.)

Comment: I think you are overthinking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'oh. I wasn't realizing that `map` also returns an `Optional` of the type being mapped. So all along it was...

```
Optional<String> s = fooMaybe.map(Foo::getName);
```

I'll keep this question open for other newbies tripping over their own feet.